# Ruby -e does not execute the code in the argument

Tags: terminal, homebrew, ruby

I am running Mac OS High Sierra v10.13.2 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012). My Ruby version (output from `>ruby -v)` is `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]`.
When I am trying to install Homebrew using the following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install")
```

the command returns a prompt ">", and nothing happens. When I try running the curl command, it executes properly and displays the Homebrew install scipt.

How do I get the entire "ruby -e ..." command to execute properly and install Homebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"` around the link are unnecessary, but there is one `"` missing at the end. Try

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

or just copy/paste from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).